# Shutdown failed with error 10038

Tags: c++, visual-studio, sockets, winsock, shutdown

I am making a Winsock application, and something fails in the server when it tries to make the shutdown funtion. The project builds and runs, but when the first connection of the client arrives it takes it and fails showing in the comand line: 
"shutdown failed with error: 10038".
I have been reading about the error and it is said that it is usually because the funcion shutdown is applied to something that is not a SOCKET, or like that. But when debugging I saw that apparently it is a Socket, so I don't know what to do.

```
#undef UNICODE

#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN

#include "stdafx.h"

// Need to link with Ws2_32.lib
#pragma comment (lib, "Ws2_32.lib")
// #pragma comment (lib, "Mswsock.lib")

#define DEFAULT_BUFLEN 512
#define DEFAULT_PORT "27015"
//Function declaration
const std::string currentDateTime();
int __cdecl NewClient(SOCKET ListenSocket, SOCKET ClientSocket, char *recvbuf,  int recvbuflen, int iSendResult, int iResult);
std::string CommandGet(char *recvbuf);
void Login(char *recvbuf);
void print_data(char *recvbuf);
string GetUsername(char *recvbuf);
string GetThirdToken(char *recvbuf);

//Map & Struct creation
struct message{
    static unsigned int last_id;
    unsigned int id;
    std::string baa;
    std::string timestamp;
    message(){};
    message(const std::string& recvbuf_baa,const std::string& a_timestamp) :
    baa(recvbuf_baa), timestamp(a_timestamp), id(++last_id)
  {
  }
};
map<std::string,std::vector<message *> > data;
map<std::string,std::vector<string> > followers;
//Global variables
unsigned int message::last_id = 0;
map<std::string,bool> loggedin;

int __cdecl main(void) 
{
    WSADATA wsaData;
    int iResult;

    SOCKET ListenSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
    SOCKET ClientSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;

    struct addrinfo *result = NULL;
    struct addrinfo hints;



    int iSendResult=0;
    char recvbuf[DEFAULT_BUFLEN];
    int recvbuflen = DEFAULT_BUFLEN;

    // Initialize Winsock
    iResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2), &wsaData);
    if (iResult != 0) {
        printf("WSAStartup failed with error: %d\n", iResult);
        return 1;
    }

    ZeroMemory(&hints, sizeof(hints));
    hints.ai_family = AF_INET;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;
    hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE;
    while(true){
        // Resolve the server address and port
        iResult = getaddrinfo(NULL, DEFAULT_PORT, &hints, &result);
        if ( iResult != 0 ) {
            printf("getaddrinfo failed with error: %d\n", iResult);
            WSACleanup();
            return 1;
        }

        // Create a SOCKET for connecting to server
        ListenSocket = socket(result->ai_family, result->ai_socktype, result->ai_protocol);
        if (ListenSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
            printf("socket failed with error: %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());
            freeaddrinfo(result);
            WSACleanup();
            return 1;
        }

        // Setup the TCP listening socket
        iResult = ::bind( ListenSocket, result->ai_addr, (int)result->ai_addrlen);
        if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
            printf("bind failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
            freeaddrinfo(result);
            closesocket(ListenSocket);
            WSACleanup();
            return 1;
        }

        freeaddrinfo(result);

        iResult = listen(ListenSocket, SOMAXCONN);
        if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
            printf("listen failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
            closesocket(ListenSocket);
            WSACleanup();
            return 1;
        }
        // Accept a client socket
        ClientSocket = accept(ListenSocket, NULL, NULL);
        if (ClientSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
            printf("accept failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
            closesocket(ListenSocket);
            WSACleanup();
            return 1;
        }

        // No longer need server socket
        closesocket(ListenSocket);

         return NewClient(ListenSocket, ClientSocket, recvbuf, recvbuflen, iSendResult, iResult);



    }
}

int __cdecl NewClient(SOCKET ListenSocket, SOCKET ClientSocket,  char *recvbuf,  int recvbuflen, int iSendResult, int iResult){



        // Receive until the peer shuts down the connection
        do {
            iResult = recv(ClientSocket, recvbuf, recvbuflen, 0);
            if (iResult > 0) {
                printf("Bytes received: %d\n", iResult);
                std::string cmd=CommandGet(recvbuf);
                if (cmd=="log"){
                    std::string usrn=GetUsername(recvbuf);
                    std::string recvbuf_str="";
                    for(auto it=loggedin.begin();it!=loggedin.end();it++){
                        if ((*it).first==usrn){
                            recvbuf_str="loggedin";
                            if ((*it).second){
                                recvbuf_str="cantlogin";
                                break;
                            }
                            else{
                                loggedin[usrn]=1;
                                break;
                            }
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    if (recvbuf_str==""){
                        recvbuf_str="newlogin";
                        Login(recvbuf);
                    }
                    iSendResult = send( ClientSocket, recvbuf_str.c_str(), iResult, 0 );
                    if (iSendResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
                        printf("send failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
                        closesocket(ClientSocket);
                        WSACleanup();
                          return 1;
                    }
                }


            }

            else if (iResult == 0){
                printf("Connection closing...\n");
                closesocket(ClientSocket);}
            else  {
                printf("recv failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
                closesocket(ClientSocket);
                WSACleanup();
                  return 1;
            }

        } while (iResult > 0);


    // shutdown the connection since we're done
    iResult = shutdown(ClientSocket, SD_SEND);
    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        printf("shutdown failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(ClientSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    // cleanup
    closesocket(ClientSocket);
    WSACleanup();

    return 0;
}
const std::string currentDateTime() {
    time_t     now = time(0);
    struct tm  tstruct;
    char       buf[80];
    localtime_s(&tstruct, &now);
    strftime(buf, sizeof(buf), "%Y-%m-%d %X", &tstruct);
    return buf;
}

void Login(char *recvbuf){
    std::string usrn= GetUsername(recvbuf);
    std::vector<message *> messages;
    data[usrn]=messages;
    std::vector<string> follow;
    followers[usrn]=follow;
    loggedin[usrn]=1;
}


void print_data(char *recvbuf){
    std::string usrn= GetUsername(recvbuf);

    for(auto mapIt = data.cbegin(); mapIt != data.cend(); ++mapIt)
    {
    std::cout << "printing data for " << mapIt->first << ":" << std::endl;
    for(auto vectIter = mapIt->second.cbegin(); vectIter != mapIt->second.cend(); ++vectIter)
        {
            std::cout << (*vectIter)->baa << ", " << (*vectIter)->timestamp << ", "
                  << (*vectIter)->id << std::endl;
        }
    }
}

void print_followers(char *recvbuf){
    std::string usrn= GetUsername(recvbuf);

    for(auto mapIt = followers.cbegin(); mapIt != followers.cend(); ++mapIt)
    {
    std::cout << "printing followers for " << mapIt->first << ":" << std::endl;
    for(auto vectIter = mapIt->second.cbegin(); vectIter != mapIt->second.cend(); ++vectIter)
        {
            std::cout << (*vectIter) << endl;
        }
    }
}

std::string CommandGet(char *recvbuf){
        int start0=0;
        std::string recvbuf_cmd;
        std::string recvstr(recvbuf);
        start0=recvstr.find(';');
        recvbuf_cmd=recvstr.substr(0,start0);
        return recvbuf_cmd;
}

string GetUsername(char *recvbuf){
    int start0=0, start1=0;
    std::string recvbuf_usrn;
    std::string recvstr(recvbuf);
    start0=recvstr.find(';');
    start1=recvstr.find(';',start0+1);
    recvbuf_usrn=recvstr.substr(start0+1,start1-start0-1);
    return recvbuf_usrn;
}

string GetThirdToken(char *recvbuf){
    int start0=0, start1=0, start2=0;
    std::string recvbuf_thirdtoken;
    std::string recvstr(recvbuf);
    start0=recvstr.find(';');
    start1=recvstr.find(';',start0+1);
    start2=recvstr.find(';',start1+1);
    recvbuf_thirdtoken=recvstr.substr(start1+1,start2-start1-1);
    return recvbuf_thirdtoken;
}
```

I upload the whole project in case you want to check it deeper( https://mega.nz/#!dtcx1DCL!dKWV2ryDDfiXv5H3Mi2p4PrBpie2CGrGJOTAwvQAV8M), but the problem is located in the server(which i simplified the code), the client is just so you can start the conection entering the username(but dont care about it).

Thank you in advance, any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Don't give us "the whole project", especially as a link that can go stale and make the whole question worthless. Instead try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to show us, *in the question body*. and if you have trouble doing that then extract the relevant parts from the actual code and show us, *also* in the body of the question. And if you haven't done so yet, please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @JoachimPileborg thank you for your answer, I edited the question to provide the server code directly in the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lets consider the following lines, take from your shown source:

```
iResult = recv(ClientSocket, recvbuf, recvbuflen, 0);
...
else if (iResult == 0){
    printf("Connection closing...\n");
    closesocket(ClientSocket);}
...
iResult = shutdown(ClientSocket, SD_SEND);
```

When [`recv`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740121%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) returns zero that means the connection has been closed (nicely) by the other end. When that happens you call [`closesocket`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms737582%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to close the socket. ***But*** then you proceed to unconditionally call [`shutdown`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740481%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) on the closed socket, leading to the error you got.

Simple solution? Just close the socket using `closesocket` *once*, no need for `shutdown` here that I can see (there seldom are).

Comment: thanks for your answer, i had tried this but if I do this, the server closes when the first connection is finished, and i want it to still be listening for the next command, what can i do?

Comment: @19mike95 That's a completely different problem, and to solve that you should take a close look at the logic in your `main` function. If you can't follow your own code manually, then I suggest you step through it line by line in a debugger. If you don't know how to fix it then it's the subject for another question.